# Qlikview - Count IF A = X AND B != Y OR Z

Tags: logic, qlikview

As the title says, I'm trying to get a count of data that follows the logic above. What I have so far;

`=COUNT(IF(A='X', A AND IF(B <> 'Y' OR B <> 'Z', B)))`

I'm aware I could do a set analysis, but A) doing so makes it so that selecting a different value of A still shows all data where A = X and B) I want to figure this out.

Comment: So, to clarify, if this was SQL, you'd want the following?  
SELECT
  Count(*)
FROM
  SomeTable
WHERE
  A = 'X'
  AND (B <> 'Y' OR B <> 'Z')

Comment: That is correct, yes.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd encourage using set analysis. If you're going this route, however, I think that it's easier to read if you switch to using the Sum function:

Sum(If(A='X' AND (B <> 'Y' OR B <> 'Z'), 1, 0))

Comment: This works if changed to Sum(If(A='X' AND (B <> 'Y' AND B <> 'Z'), 1, 0)).

Comment: I think that De Morgan's laws muddied the translation of what you were asking for to my SQL restatement of it, but if it works for you, declare victory and walk away. Good luck!